# NullPointerException: null while trying to do a MongoDB FindByID

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, nullpointerexception

So i'm trying to connect java spring to mongoDB and using a findById, but it always gives the null pointer error.

```
2020-08-04 13:54:01.893 ERROR 8312 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at pt.project.ProvaConceito_BackEnd.mongoDB.UserService.findById(UserService.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at pt.project.ProvaConceito_BackEnd.mongoDB.mongoDBService.getUserByID(mongoDBService.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
```

The structure of this project is:

- Java

  - MongoDB

    - mongoDBService
    - UserService
  - Pojos

    - User
  - Repositories

    - UserRepository

I'm gonna share the code I have right now:

**mongoDBService**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import pt.project.ProvaConceito_BackEnd.pojos.User;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
public class mongoDBService {

    UserService userService = new UserService();

    @RequestMapping("/concept/user")
    public User getUserByID(Integer id) {
        return userService.findById(1);
    }
}
```

**UserService**

```
package pt.project.ProvaConceito_BackEnd.mongoDB;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import pt.project.ProvaConceito_BackEnd.pojos.User;
import pt.project.ProvaConceito_BackEnd.repositories.UserRepository;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public void save(String nome, int idade, String morada) {
        userRepository.save(new User(nome, idade, morada));
    }

    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public long count() {
        return userRepository.count();
    }

    public User findById(Integer id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    public void delete(Integer id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

}
```

**Users** (Pojo)

```
package pt.project.ProvaConceito_BackEnd.pojos;

import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "Users")
@Getter
public class User {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String nome;
    private int idade;
    private String morada;

    public User(String nome, int idade, String morada) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
        this.morada = morada;
    }
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
package pt.project.ProvaConceito_BackEnd.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import pt.project.ProvaConceito_BackEnd.pojos.User;

public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I think the problem is on mongoDBService...
in this line:

```
UserService userService = new UserService();
```

Because I think that it's not being injected, but I don't know how to solve that...

**EDIT 1**
I have my main class inside `pt.project.ProvaConceito_BackEnd`:

ProvaConceitoBackEndApplication

```
package pt.project.ProvaConceito_BackEnd;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ProvaConceitoBackEndApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProvaConceitoBackEndApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try annotating `UserService` with `@Autowired` instead of instantiating it with `new UserService()`?

Comment: I just tried that and gives the same error

Comment: Don't use `new` you should inject it. Remve the `required` and it will then probably not start anymore. Place your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in `pt.project` and restart and now it will work.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have it, just edited the post so you can check it

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `new` to create object that way because spring will not have any knowledge of that object and will not be able to inject it.

Since you have already annotated the `UserService` with `@service` you should use `@Autowired` annotation

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import pt.project.ProvaConceito_BackEnd.pojos.User;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
public class mongoDBService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/baieuropa/user")
    public User getUserByID(Integer id) {
        return userService.findById(1);
    }
}
```

Also annotate the `UserRepository` class with `@Repository`

```
package pt.project.ProvaConceito_BackEnd.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import pt.project.ProvaConceito_BackEnd.pojos.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

Remove `required = false` from `UserService` class

Make sure to have a class with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation in `pt.project.ProvaConceito_BackEnd` package.

Comment: I just tried that and didn't worked, gave me the same exact error. But I think it's a problem of  @Autowired because if I remove the "required = false" from UserService it gives me a compiling error:
Field userRepository in pt.project.ProvaConceito_BackEnd.mongoDB.UserService required a bean of type 'pt.project.ProvaConceito_BackEnd.repositories.UserRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Comment: Annotate the `UserRepository` class with `@Repository` and remove `required = false`

Comment: Where do you have `@SpringBootApplication` ? It should be on a class which is at `pt.project.ProvaConceito_BackEnd` package

Comment: You still  get same error after adding `@Repository`?Can you commit the code in some repo in GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your repository and User.class to have an ID type of string instead of Integer. This is required for mongo repositories. May not completely solve your problem but will be a step in the right direction

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I made the changes but yeah, still have the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the suggestions of other contributors to remove the "new" keyword from your mongoDBService and use the @Repository annotation too.

Autowiring only works if all components that it relies on are autowired too. So in your case because the mongoDBService uses new for the UserService then it expects the Repository to use "new" too. You should instead autowire at all levels and remove the required=false from the autowiring in the UserService.

The repository requires the @Repository annotation otherwise when Spring does its component scan the repository wont be picked up without it. @Repository @RestController etc are all just stereotypes for @Component with varying degrees of additional functionality

Comment: Also your User constructor does not have an id in it